How to install gopls LSP for nvim
I have a problem installing gopls LSP for Neovim. I installed go but when I install the gopls server using mason, I have this message:


    ✗ gopls
  ▼ Displaying full log
    Installing go package golang.org/x/tools/gopls@v0.15.2…
    golang.org/x/tools/internal/event/keys
    golang.org/x/tools/internal/diff
    golang.org/x/tools/gopls/internal/util/frob
    # golang.org/x/tools/internal/diff
    /home/yossef/go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/tools@v0.18.1-0.20240311201521-78fbdeb61842/internal/diff/ndiff.go:92:13: error: expected ‘(’
       92 | func isASCII[S string | []byte](s S) bool {
          |             ^
    /home/yossef/go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/tools@v0.18.1-0.20240311201521-78fbdeb61842/internal/diff/ndiff.go:92:16: error: expected ‘]’
       92 | func isASCII[S string | []byte](s S) bool {
          |                ^
    /home/yossef/go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/tools@v0.18.1-0.20240311201521-78fbdeb61842/internal/diff/ndiff.go:92:16: error: expected ‘;’ or newline after top level declaration
    /home/yossef/go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/tools@v0.18.1-0.20240311201521-78fbdeb61842/internal/diff/ndiff.go:93:21: error: expected declaration
       93 |         for i := 0; i < len(s); i++ {
          |                     
 ....
 ....
 ....
          |         ^
    /home/yossef/go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/tools@v0.18.1-0.20240311201521-78fbdeb61842/go/ssa/util.go:379:9: error: expected declaration
      379 |         return vals
          |         ^
    /home/yossef/go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/tools@v0.18.1-0.20240311201521-78fbdeb61842/go/ssa/util.go:381:1: error: expected declaration
      381 | }
          | ^
    spawn: go failed with exit code 2 and signal 0. 

Go version:
go version go1.18 gccgo (GCC) 13.2.1 20240316 (Red Hat 13.2.1-7) linux/amd64
How to solve this problem ???

Please include text as text, not as images.

done , but the error massage was 500 line and I cut it

Is the version of go you are using recent enough? That seems to be complaining about generics syntax.

Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?

As per https://github.com/golang/tools/tree/master/gopls#supported-go-versions, gopls only supports two releases before the latest.
Go 1.18 is thus supported by goplus only through version gopls@v0.14.2, and the version you're trying to install (0.15.2) is newer. Either pin that version of gopls, or use a newer build of Go.
